# ¿Por que no me sale el mensaje de alerta con validación en un formulario?

Tags: javascript, css, html5, formularios

```
<form id="info" action="">
            <div class="izquierda">
            <label for="">Nombres y Apellidos:</label>
            <input name="txtNombre" type="text" placeholder="Ingrese Datos">
                <label for="">Distrito:</label> 
            <select name="cboDistrito">
                <option value="Selecciona">Seleccione...</option>
                <option value="Ancon">Ancon</option>
                <option value="Ate">Ate</option>
                <option value="Barranco">Barranco</option>
                <option value="Breña">Breña</option>
           </select><br>

        <label for="">Dirección:</label>
                <input type="text" name="txtDireccion" placeholder="Ingrese Datos">
            <label for="">Celular:</label>
                <input type="text" name="txtTelefono" placeholder="999-999-999">
            <label for="">E-mail:</label>
                <input type="text" name="txtCorreo" placeholder="Example@gmail.com">    
            <label for="">Describe tu pedido:</label>
                <textarea  id="txtS" cols="50" rows="8"></textarea>
            <label for="" class="forma">Forma de pago:</label>
            </div>

            <div class="pago">

                <div class="entrega">
                    <img class="icopago" src="imagenes/contraentrega.JPG">
                    <p>Pago contra entrega</p>
                    <input type="radio" name="pago" value="contraEntrega">
                </div>
                <div class="entrega">
                    <img class="icopago" src="imagenes/deposito.jpg" alt="" >
                    <p>Deposito en cuenta bancaria</p>
                    <input type="radio" name="pago" value="deposito">
                </div>

            </div>

            <div class="terminos">
                <p>El delivery se realiza por compras mayores de 50 soles y será gratuito para zonas aledañas a Santa Anita, en caso contrario se aplicará un recargo de 20 soles .</p>
                <p>Los pedidos se deben realizar con 10 días de anticipación a la fecha de entrega.</p>
                <p>En menos de 24 horas se le enviará un correo confirmando su pedido .</p>
                <p>No existen reembolsos.</p><br>
                <div class="term">
                    <input type="radio" name="acepto" value="AceptoTerminosCondicones">   
                    <p class="condi">Acepto Términos y Condicones</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <input type="submit" value="Realizar pedido" class="boton"> 
        </form>

</select><br>

        <label for="">Dirección:</label>
                <input type="text" name="txtDireccion" placeholder="Ingrese Datos">
            <label for="">Celular:</label>
                <input type="text" name="txtTelefono" placeholder="999-999-999">
            <label for="">E-mail:</label>
                <input type="text" name="txtCorreo" placeholder="Example@gmail.com">    
            <label for="">Describe tu pedido:</label>
                <textarea  id="txtS" cols="50" rows="8"></textarea>
            <label for="" class="forma">Forma de pago:</label>
            </div>

            <div class="pago">

                <div class="entrega">
                    <img class="icopago" src="imagenes/contraentrega.JPG">
                    <p>Pago contra entrega</p>
                    <input type="radio" name="pago" value="contraEntrega">
                </div>
                <div class="entrega">
                    <img class="icopago" src="imagenes/deposito.jpg" alt="" >
                    <p>Deposito en cuenta bancaria</p>
                    <input type="radio" name="pago" value="deposito">
                </div>

            </div>

            <div class="terminos">
                <p>El delivery se realiza por compras mayores de 50 soles y será gratuito para zonas aledañas a Santa Anita, en caso contrario se aplicará un recargo de 20 soles .</p>
                <p>Los pedidos se deben realizar con 10 días de anticipación a la fecha de entrega.</p>
                <p>En menos de 24 horas se le enviará un correo confirmando su pedido .</p>
                <p>No existen reembolsos.</p><br>
                <div class="term">
                    <input type="radio" name="acepto" value="AceptoTerminosCondicones">   
                    <p class="condi">Acepto Términos y Condicones</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <input type="submit" value="Realizar pedido" class="boton"> 
        </form>


//Validacion de formulario
var env = document.getElementsById("info");
env.onsubmit = Enviar;

function Enviar(){
    var nom = document.getElementsByName("txtNombre")[0].value;
    var cor = document.getElementsByName("txtCorreo")[0].value;
    var tel = document.getElementsByName("txtTelefono")[0].value;
    var dir = document.getElementsByName("txtDireccion")[0].value;
    var area = document.getElementById("txtS").value;
    var val;
    val = /^[a-zA-Z]+(\s[a-zA-Z]+)*$/;
    if(!val.test(nom)){
        alert("Ingresar solo texto en el nombre");
        document.getElementsByName("txtNombre")[0].value = "";
        return false;
    }


    val = /^[a-zA-Z0-9\-_\.]+\@[a-zA-Z0-9\-_]+(\.[a-z]{2,4}){1,2}$/;
    if(!val.test(cor)) {
        alert("El correo es incorrecto");
        document.getElementsByName("txtCorreo")[0].value = "";
        return false;
    }

    val=/^[0-9]{9}$/;
    if(!val.test(tel)){
        alert("Ingresar solo número en el de Teléfono");
        document.getElementsByName("txtTelefono")[0].value = "";
        return false;
    }

    if(dir == ""){
        alert("Ingrese su dirección");
        return false;
    }

    if(area == ""){
        alert("Ingrese información que desea recibir");
        return false;
    }
    alert("Datos Enviados Correctamente");
    env.submit();
}
```

[Imagen del formulario: no sé por qué razón no sale la alerta de error en llenar el formulario, si fuera posible me podrían decir mi error, todavía me falta validar las demás opciones si fuera posible me podrían ayudar en la validación](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kHw5r.png)

Comment: y en que parte estas diciendo que haga la validación antes de enviar?, no veo que uses la función

Comment: Trata de depurar tu código, hay muchas cosas que no entiendo, cierras un select luego de un input, cerraste el form 2 veces pero abriste sólo uno. No sé que quieres lograr

Answer (score 0):

El código tiene dos errores:

1. El script debe ir entre los tags `<script type="text/javascript">` y `</script>`
2. Donde dice `document.getElementsById("info");` está en plural, debería ser `document.getElementById("info");`

Con esos dos cambios ya debería funcionar.
Suerte!